# pg_ctlcluster with --log option

Tags: postgresql

https://askubuntu.com/questions/385416/pg-ctl-command-not-found-what-package-has-this-command/385970#385970
say that I should use `pg_ctlcluster`.

`sudo pg_ctlcluster 14 main  start` is OK.

But the man page (https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/pg_ctlcluster.8.html) say that `pg_ctlcluster`  can also use `[pg_ctl options].`
`pg_ctlcluster [options] cluster-version cluster-name action -- [pg_ctl options]`

So How do I use it also customize the log location.
All the following command I've been tried all are failed.

`sudo pg_ctlcluster 14 main  start --l  /home/jian/postgresql_lg/1.log`  
`sudo pg_ctlcluster 14 main  start -l  /home/jian/postgresql_lg/1.log`
`sudo pg_ctlcluster 14 main  stop --log  /home/jian/postgresql_lg/1.log`

The error almost the same:
`Unknown option: log`  
`Unknown option: l`

Comment: You need a literal ` -- ` (with the spaces but without the quotes) before giving the pg_ctl options.  Otherwise it still thinks you are giving pg_ctlcluster options. This seems like the wrong way to do whatever you want to do anyway.  Why don't you edit the config file, unless you are just trying to make a one time exception.

Comment: `Error: /usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/pg_ctl /usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/pg_ctl start -D /var/lib/postgresql/14/main -l /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-14-main.log l /home/jian/postgresql_lg/1.log -s -o  -c config_file="/etc/postgresql/14/main/postgresql.conf"  exited with status 1:
pg_ctl: too many command-line arguments (first is "start")` I already set the logfile. I know where is my logfile. Yes. i want one time exception and only log small part of operation. It's just failed. @jjanes

Comment: It looks like you used just `l`, not either `-l` or `--log`, after the dash dash space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this works.

```
 sudo pg_ctlcluster 12 main  start -- --log  /home/jian/postgresql_lg/1.log
```

But the directory needs to writable by the OS user who will be running PostgreSQL.